# Powershell Pull AD Group and Subgroup Endless Loop

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

My script is hitting the active directory to pull AD groups and their subgroups.

I will be adding in `Get-ADGroupMember Where-Object { $_.ObjectClass -eq "user" })` to the script but right now the script runs endlessly.

I checked the CSV file and data is being pushed into it, I just do not know why this is running endlessly.

I am still new to Powershell and may have overlooked something.

Do I need to add some sort of `catch` or `exit`? I read that `exit` closes the loop before it can execute completely.

**My Script:**

```
Clear-Host

#Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Starting" 

$logfile = "C:\temp\logfile.csv"
"Domains,Groups,Nested" | Add-Content $logfile

$grp_list = Import-Csv "C:\temp\Copy_lp.csv"
$domains = @()    
$dom = Import-Csv "C:\temp\Copy_lp.csv" |
    Select-Object -Unique -ExpandProperty "Domain Group"

foreach ($domain in $dom) {
    $domains += $domain.Split('\')[0]
}

$domains = $domains | Select-Object -Unique

foreach ($domain in $domains) {

    Write-Host "Domain:" $domain
    Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Server $domain |

    ForEach-Object {
        $group = $_.Name

        $grps = (Get-ADGroupMember $group -Server $domain |
            Where-Object { $_.ObjectClass -eq "Group" })

        $grps | ForEach {
            Write-Host "Group: " $_.Name 
            "$domain,$($_.Name),$group" | Add-Content $logfile
        }
    }
}

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Done"
```

**Update**
This was answered by Tomer. I had taken the output CSV from a previous script that was executed to look at user permissions at the database level. So when a user was mapped to multiple databases (user also belonged to different groups and subgroups) within the instance and would appear numerous times. So as my script went through the list it would re-run the same AD Group(s) over and over. I still do not understand why it would continuously run but once I altered the CSV file to have just a domain list it executed and spit out the output I was looking for. I did not put this as the answer because I felt Tomer deserved the credit. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: I was incorrect. Using the domain in the server parameter is acceptable.

Comment: @BenH I thought so as after the changes it would not connect. So I am sure I need to put some sort catch in it just not sure where. Maybe in the second ForEach loop?

Comment: If a catch loop would catch the error, then it would be terminating. So if you would need to add `-erroraction stop`. Where I would start is to add a couple more write-hosts in your loops to pinpoint where you get in your script before it hangs.

Comment: It seems to be getting caught up in the 
    `$grps | ForEach {
                Write-Host "Group: " $_.Name 
                "$domain,$($_.Name),$group" | Add-Content $logfile
            }`

Comment: Hi, if you remove this part, does the script end? You can [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41510761/edit) to add details and results.

Comment: Perhaps there's a group which is a member of itself (not necessarily directly). I would check for duplicates in the log file.

Comment: @sodawillow It kept looping even when removing it.

Comment: @Tomer Bingo, I never thought about that as CSV file list had users from various domains repeated (due to permissions) so it took that list and kept going into the same domains. You should post the answer to get credit. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Active Directory, membership self-loops are permitted. So for example, group A may contain another group B which may contain group A again. Therefore, simple enumeration of the member-of relation can lead to an infinite loop.

An easy way to solve it is to store the DNs you've already seen, and not going over them again.